# how to convert anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)] to swift3

Tags: swift

How to convert responsetoselector into swift3 . if i converted getting static method calling error for responds(to: )

```
- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)anObject { 
     if ([anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)])
     { 
        return [anObject stringValue]; 
     } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift instead of checking if a class responds to a selector, you use *optional chaining* to call the method:

```
func stringForObjectValue(anObject: AnyObject) -> String? {
    return anObject.stringValue?()
}
```

Note that the method has to be one available to the Objective-C runtime.  So if you implement `stringValue` for your own class, it needs to be preceded by `@objc`.

```
class Foo {
    @objc func stringValue() -> String {
        return "Foo baby"
    }
}

class Bar {
    // It works with properties too
    @objc var stringValue = "Bar bar Jinx"
}

class Baz {
    // This method not available to Objective-C
    func stringValue() -> String {
        return "Baz Baz bo Baz"
    }
}

stringForObjectValue(anObject: Foo())  // "Foo baby"
stringForObjectValue(anObject: Bar())  // "Bar bar Jinx"
stringForObjectValue(anObject: Baz())  // nil
```

For more information, read about [AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyobject), especially the section titled *"Accessing Objective-C Methods and Properties"*.